# What are some of the earliest examples of songs featuring blast beats in triple metre?

Tags: history, metal

For those who may not know, [triple metre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_metre) most often applies to songs with time signatures of 3 or 9. For the purposes of my question, I will include 6, 12, etc. even though they are usually considered to be [compound metres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(music)#Compound_metre).

As a metalhead, I have heard a million songs with blast beats but only a handful of such songs in triple metre. All I know is that I really like the ones I have heard.

What are some of the earliest examples of songs featuring blast beats in triple metre?